# Applying Template to Dynamic Chart Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, templates, charts, apply

I have created a dashboard. Sometimes the dynamic charts lose their format (when the slicer selections gets no data)

Once "good" data is selected, regular charts return to proper template, but dynamic charts are all messed up.

I wanna create a macro to reset the charts templates by applying saved templates. The macro isn't running.

```vb
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("IncrementoMínimo").Activate

ActiveChart.ApplyChartTemplate ("C:\Users\danie\OlaKase\\Plantillas Gráficos\Incremento Mínimo.crtx")
```

[image: error displayed]

I don't know why, it is working in another file.

```vb
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Gráfico 8").Activate

ActiveChart.ApplyChartTemplate ("C:\Users\danie\AppData\\Gráfico2.crtx")
```

The file where it's working ok:
The dynamic chart is from a single table.
All the data labels come from a dynamic table.

The file where it's not working:
The dynamic charts are from Power Pivot Tables, is combining 4 tables.
Some of the data labels are from cells.

[image: ideal design]

[image: messed up design]

Answer (score 0):

I suspect unchecking the [Properties Follow Chart Data Point](https://peltiertech.com/properties-follow-chart-data-point/) setting in the Advanced Options (the link is to a tutorial I've written about this).

Click on Excel’s File tab on the ribbon, choose Options, then click on Advanced. Scroll down to Chart, and you’ll see “Properties Follow Chart Data Point for All New Workbooks” and “Properties Follow Chart Data Point for Current Workbook”.

Uncheck the box for the current workbook, and see if the problems with dynamic data remains.

Comment: Thx. Doesn't work, but thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Already solved: i had "protected sheet" LMAO. Just removed protection with vba. Thanks to everyone.